# Fastest way to fill a 2D ndarray like an histogram

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have to fill a `numpy.ndarray` that counts `votes` (in order to compute correlations), so it's like filling a 2D histogram:

```
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        votes[array1[y,x], array2[y,x]] += 1
```

What is the fastest way to do it, because implemented like that it takes ages.

[Edit]: Numba is not an option as it does not support a double indexing like `votes[array1[y,x], array2[y,x]]`

Comment: can you provie some test data for `array1` and `array2`?

Comment: I simply take two images with labeled patterns. The array `votes` then contains the overlap between the different patterns.